# VB6 licensing for controls?

Tags: vb6, licensing

In the components section I selected a IMAGE VIEWER ACTIVEX CONTROL, which is a third party component. I tried to use it in my application, however, whenever I click on the object in the TOOLBOX window and drag it to my form, I get this message...

```
**License information for this component not found. You do not have an appropriate license to use this functionality in the design environment.**
```

Now the thing is, i actually do have a license for this component. Its in the folder with all my forms and modules, its titled imageviewer.lic

It seems as though the license is there, it does not get applied to the image viewer control. Not sure how to go about resolving this. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "license file," and where did you get it?  If this is an `LPK` file then it won't help you since that would be a run-time license package for use within an HTML page in IE.  If you have something else it would help to describe what it is you have.

Comment: it's a third party license. Basically it says blahblah.lic. My application for some reason is not recognizing it, even tho it is the proper license.

Comment: I assume this license file is a file with `.LIC` extension. From memory you might need to copy the .LIC file to `Windows\System32`. Or else to the same folder where the OCX file is installed.